# R: Returning a Frequency Table from a list of Dataframes

Tags: r, frequency, mapply

The goal is to return the following:

```
#   table     variable attribute frequency
#   mammal    dog      akita     50    
#   mammal    dog      boxer     25
#   mammal    dog      vizsla    25
#   mammal    cat      sphinx    5
#   amphibian fish     guppy     100
#   amphibian fish     cod       20
```

Each animal class is stored in a dataframe on a list and within that dataframe each animal is an occurrence with their own row. If I was working with only one animal class and therefore only one table (titled class), I would use the following code to make the transformation:

```
#create list of frequencies for each attribute 
freq <- lapply(class, function(attribute) {
   j <- as.data.frame(sort(table(attribute), decreasing=True)[1:10])
})
#convert list to a data frame
freq_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(freq, as.data.frame))
freq_frame <- cbind(variable = rownames(freq_frame), freq_frame)
freq_frame$variable <- gsub("\\.{1-9]*", "", freq_frame$variable)
```

Since this only works on one table I would like to apply it to the list of dataframes through mapply, but since this is multiple transformations, I keep receiving errors or not the correct formatting.

Does anyone know how I might be able to make these transformations over a list of dataframes?

Comment: It is better to show a small input data for testing, preferably with `dput`.  If the code showed is for a single dataframe, then you can wrap this in a function and use `lapply(yourlist, fn)`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).